# ajax post callback function not working

Tags: ajax

Here is index.php

```
post_data = {'username':username, 'old_pass':old_pass, 'new_pass':new_pass};

$.post('change_pass.php', post_data, function(result) {
    if(result.text == 'success') {
        $("#message").text("Password changed successfully");
    } else {
        $("#message").text("Error changing password");
    }
}, 'json');
```

and the change_pass.php is

```
<?php
    @mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Connection problem');
    @mysql_select_db("my_db");

    $username = filter_var($_POST["username"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $old_pass = filter_var($_POST["old_pass"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $new_pass = filter_var($_POST["new_pass"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `pass`='".$new_pass."' WHERE `pass`='".$old_pass."' AND `user`='".$username."'")) == 1) {
        $output = json_encode(array('text' => 'success'));
        die($output);
    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array('text' => 'failure'));
        die($output);
    }

?>
```

The password changing happens successfully but the callback doesn't work. why?

But the callback works if I avoid the query. So I think something goes wrong when i use the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the PHP `json_encode(array())`-function returns a JSON-object wrapped in an array. Like this:

```
[{text: 'success'}]
```

The ajax result would hence be:

```
$.post('change_pass.php', post_data, function(result) {
 if(result[0].text == 'success') {
    $("#message").text("Password changed successfully");
  } else {
    $("#message").text("Error changing password");
  }
}, 'json');
```

Try it out? Also: I'm not sure if aborting the page with `die()` is the best thing to do. I suggest you instead echo the result and then return. Like this:

```
echo json_encode(array('text' => 'success'));
return;
```

**Edit:**
Then I suggest you reformat your ajax request more like this:

```
$.post( 'change_pass.php', post_data)
.done(function( result ) {
  // Check what result will get you in the console (Ctrl + Shift + J in chrome)
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the thing is, even though I tried function(result { alert("this is a trial"); } not working.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this :

```
 if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `pass`='".$new_pass."' WHERE `pass`='".$old_pass."' AND `user`='".$username."'")) == 1) {
        $output = json_encode(array('text' => 'success'));
        echo $output;
        return;
    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array('text' => 'failure'));
        echo $output;
        return;
    }
```